# Can all large integer $n \times(n+1)$ rectangles be tiled with smaller copies of distinct $k\times(k+1)$ rectangles?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, rectangles, tiling

Can all large integer $n\times(n+1)$ rectangles be tiled with smaller copies of distinct $k\times(k+1)$ rectangles?  It seems to be true for $n\geq20$, but I don't see how to do it in general.

https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0512.html

Comment: So "almost squares in almost squares" near the bottom of that page

Comment: that is correct.